# Python regex splitting additionally on _

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to split a string in python using regular expressions. This line works almost perfectly for me:

```
from string import punctuation
import re
row = re.findall('\w+|[{0}]+'.format(punctuation), string)
```

However, it doesn't split the string on instances of _ as well. For instance:

```
>>> string = "Hi my name is _Mark. I like apples!! Do you?!"
>>> row = re.findall('\w+|[{0}]+'.format(punctuation), string)
>>> row
['Hi', 'my', 'name', 'is', '_Mark', '.', 'I', 'like', 'apples', '!!', 'Do', 'you', '?!']
```

What i want is:

```
['Hi', 'my', 'name', 'is', '_', 'Mark', '.', 'I', 'like', 'apples', '!!', 'Do', 'you', '?!']
```

I've read its because _ is considered a character. Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: `re.findall('\w+|[{0}]+|_+'.format(punctuation), string)`

Comment: ^ The above still gives me the same problem: _Mark

Answer (score 3):

Since `\w` will match the underscore, you can more directly specify what you consider a character without too much more work:

```
 re.findall('[a-zA-Z0-9]+|[{0}]+'.format(punctuation), string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the left side of a disjunction will always match first if possible, you can simply include `_` with the punctuation characters *before* you match letters:

```
row = re.findall(r'[{0}_]+|\w+'.format(string.punctuation), mystring)
```

But you can do the same without bothering with `string.punctuation` at all. "Punctuation" is anything that's neither a space nor a word character:

```
row = re.findall(r"(?:[^\s\w]|_)+|\w+", mystring)
```

PS. In your code sample, the string named `string` "shadows" the module `string`. Don't do that, it's bad practice and leads to bugs.

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly stated in [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=re#module-re) that `\w` not only include alphanumerical characters but also the underscore as well:

> \w
>
> When the LOCALE and UNICODE flags are not specified, matches any
>   alphanumeric character and the underscore; this is equivalent to the
>   set [a-zA-Z0-9_]. With LOCALE, it will match the set [0-9_] plus
>   whatever characters are defined as alphanumeric for the current
>   locale. If UNICODE is set, this will match the characters [0-9_] plus
>   whatever is classified as alphanumeric in the Unicode character
>   properties database.

so like Eric pointed out in his solution, better specify a set of only alphanumerical characters `[a-zA-Z0-9]`